# How to resolve the "A connection attempt failed" while sending mails from remote server

Tags: asp.net

I am getting below error while sending mails from my webpage.

**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.220.37.168:587**

Please let me know how to resolve this error.My mail sending code is.

```
public void sendmail(string emailaddress, string batchid)
    {
        try
        {


            string msg1 = string.Empty;

            string mailLink = @"http://tk5sdatweb02:2222/SitePages/Sales%20Desk%20Request%20A%20Service.aspx?MBUP=Yes&BatchID= "+batchid;

            string strSubject = "Sales Desk Internal Bulk Upload";

            string msg2 = string.Empty;


            msg1 = "Test Email for" +batchid;

                msg1 = "<html><head><body>";
                msg2 = "<span style='font-size:14px;font-family:Calibri;'>Hi REDMOND\\v-rejinn";
                msg2 = msg2 + @"<br/><br/><span style='font-size:14px;font-family:Calibri;'>A target list has recently been uploaded they will be send to SDAT.<br/>";

                msg2 = msg2 + @"To view and/or validate the accounts, please visit the <a href='" + mailLink + "' style='color:#0000FF;text-decoration:none;'>MBUP Page</a><br />";
                msg2 = msg2 + "If you have any questions or issues, please reach out to <a href='mailto:SDPET@microsoft.com'>SDPET@microsoft.com</a>.<br />";
                msg2 = msg2 + "<br/>&nbsp;Thank you,<br/><b><font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:28px;color:#033570;'>&nbsp;SALES</font>";
                msg2 = msg2 + "<font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:28px;color:#7ac366;'> DESK</font></b><br />";
                msg2 = msg2 + "<font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:10px;color:#3f6692;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='padding-left:11px;'>Enabling World Class Selling</span></font>";
                msg2 = msg2 + "</span></body></head></html>";

            //SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("tk5sdatsql01", 587);
            //smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            //MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sarath.hits@gmail.com", strSubject);
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sdmail@microsoft.com");
            message.From = fromAddress;
            string strmailid = string.Empty;
            strmailid = emailaddress;
            message.To.Add(strmailid);
            //message.Bcc.Add("sarath.psnr@gmail.com");
            message.Subject = strSubject;
            message.Body = msg2;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Port = 587;
            //smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sarath.hits@gmail.com", "myaccountdata");
            smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.Send(message);

            Response.Write("success");
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do other than catch the error -  as the receiving mail server is not under your control.

However, if you think that the server should be responding perhaps you could try connecting to it using other means ([like telnet](http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html)) so you can verify the port or other requirements.